# Meta rig generates rig incorrectly

Tags: rigging, rigify

[image]

Hi, I have an issue where rigify's generated rig on the legs faces the wrong way (those red arrows), it should be in front and in the back of the knees. I tried to redo the rig, rotate the bones but nothing changed, I don't know why. It's really hard to animate my object with a rig like that.

[image]

Comment: Your pelvis bones don't seem to be connected to the spine bone and are pointing forwards rather than out towards the thigh bones which look a bit strange! I think we'll need to see your Blend file to work out what's going on. You can share it via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the link on that page and then edit your question here and paste the link into it.